# mod_rewrite rule to remove comment.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to have

```
mysite.com/comment.php?id=sasdfkjsfj
```

redirected to

```
mysite.com/sasdfkjsfj.
```

Right now, i'm using this code for doing that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#redirect to remove comment.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /comment\.php\?id=([^\ &]+) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301] 

#process the SEF Url with comment.php
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z]+)$ comment.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It changes the url address to

```
mysite.com/sasdfkjsfj.
```

but that results a 404 page error. I have a separate comment.php page which is doing the job for

```
 mysite.com/comment.php?id=sasdfkjsfj
```

where i get the id by $_GET['id'] from the url but now, how to handle

```
mysite.com/sasdfkjsfj
```

after redirection.

And also what changes i have to make for this type of URL

```
mysite.com/sasdfkjsfj/Url_redirect_option.
```

Comment: Are you handling your comments via `index.php`?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey no, i have a separate page comment.php for that. And what i want is that after the redirection how to show content which was previously shown by mysite.com/comment.php?id=sasdfkjsfj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to presume you want to redirect `mysite.com/sasdfkjsfj` to `mysite.com/comment.php?id=sasdfkjsfj`; the reverese would be unusual.

Add the following .htaccess into the base web directory, or into your apache config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# if you want to use /comment/ as a base dir, as suggested by ThinkingMonkey
# then you could use this instead
# RewriteRule ^comment/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /comment.php?id=$1 [L]

# look for "mysite.com/anyasciichars" without a . or a /
# the [L] means this is the last rule processed (if it matches)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /comment.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

To handle the case of `mysite.com/sasdfkjsfj/rewrite_rule`, do something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# look for "mysite.com/anyasciichars/rewrite_rule"
# the [L] means this is the last rule processed (if it matches)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /comment.php?id=$1&rule=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```